# GWT/Mysql/Java connection to database

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

I'm fairly new to gwt, and figuring out the connections with a mysql database has me stumped. Since there are very few direct tutorials, I've been going off another stackoverflow question here.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335322/java-gwt-mysql-connection-refused/8388422#8388422
```

Although I can't get it right. Few things, this project isn't using the GAE, just the GWT, as was suggested as a previous answer in the other question. Yes, I can connect to my database through another sample program, so the link to the database is open. I also imported my mysql driver to /WEB-INF/lib, as well as added it to my java build path.

The crux of this is, I don't know why I can't connect, and my console is useless, if anyone can see right off the bat what I'm doing wrong that would be fantastic, or if there was a way to print out more of the error message that would be great as well as I don't know how to view the console for the server side resources (I read somewhere that there might be more to the errors then what is shown? ) thanks.

here is my GreetingServiceImpl.java relevant code

```
 private final Connection connect() {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dblink = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbname = "gwttest";
    String dbuser = "user";
    String dbpass = "test";
    try {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dblink + dbname, dbuser, dbpass);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.err.println("mysql connection error: ");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
  }
```

here is my helloserver.java relevant code

```
Button b = new Button("test");
vPanel.add(b);
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      GreetingServiceAsync testservice= (GreetingServiceAsync) GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
    testservice.echo("test", new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             vPanel.add(new Label("error"));
             //vPanel.add(new Label(caught.printStackTrace());
             caught.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vPanel.add(new Label(result));
        }

    });
  }
});
```

here is the error message I've recieved upon running and clicking the button (besides the "error" which pops up in my html)

```
 com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><pre>NOT_FOUND</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/helloserver/greet</p><p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>                                                
</body>
</html>
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is indicating a problem with the RPC. Database connection problems should cause an exception to be serialized to the client, not give a 404. Check that the web.xml and servlet are configured correctly. See: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.

If there were any JDBC errors, then they should be visible in the DevMode window, or in the server's log directory if running on a server. It looks like the GreetingServiceImpl class isn't reached at all though so there won't see anything there.

It may be easier to extract the JDBC code to a separate class, and test it separately from GWT. Get one thing working before combining everything together. Run it via a main method, or JUnit test, then you know whether the problem is with the JDBC code or elsewhere.

Comment: You were correct, I had changed the web.xml file and forgot to change it back. I reverted back to the original and my issues were solved.